# ¿Cómo puedo obtener datos de un Collection Map para mostrar en pantalla en Android?

Tags: java, android, json

Tengo un código donde obtengo un json desde una api en android la cual almaceno en un Map, ahora no sé como obtener esos datos que llegan al map para mostrarlos en pantalla.

Añado mi código para que se entienda mejor.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

```
private class SendBeaconParamsTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Collection<Map<String,String>>> {

    @Override
    protected Collection<Map<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {

        String UUID = params[0];
        String major = params[1];
        String minor = params[2];

        Log.d("HTTP UUID",UUID);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://cloud.easycontext.com/api/list/ibeacon?key=aNC6-qnDB-MQoi-ir3L&appid=9663261952843665&uuid="+ UUID +"&major="+major+"&minor="+minor);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

            ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int readBytes = 0;

            byte[] sBuffer = new byte[512];

            while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(sBuffer)) != -1) {
                content.write(sBuffer,0,readBytes);
            }

            String dataAsString = new String(content.toByteArray());

            Log.d("HTTP RESULT", dataAsString);

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Map<String,String>>>(){}.getType();
                Collection<Map<String,String>> collection = gson.fromJson(dataAsString,collectionType);
            return collection;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Collection<Map<String,String>> collection) {
                    Log.d("HTTP",collection.toString());
        //obtain data from the map and display
    }
}
```

mi Json es el siguiente

```
[
    {
        "id":"<id>",
        "image":"<image_url>",
        "title":"<title>",
        "description":"<description>",
        "bigtext":"<bigtext>",
        "note1":"<note1>",
        "note2":"<note2>",
        "url":"<page_url>",
        "type":"<type>"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, para evitar que cierren tu pregunta te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y lo coloques en español :)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en Inglés

Comment: ya la cambie a español, disculpen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes una colección de cualquier tipo de dato primero debes recorrerla para acceder a cada uno de los elementos, la forma más simple es usar la notación `for(... : ...)`, una vez que recorres la lista principal puedes ir accediendo a los campos del objeto como un arreglo asociativo normal, para el caso de la interfaz `Map` puedes usar `get(key)` para obtener el valor asociado a una llave.

Por ejemplo si quieres ir imprimiendo todos los títulos el código sería el siguiente:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Collection<Map<String,String>> collection) {
    for(Map<String,String> elem : collection)
           Log.d("JSON",elem.get("title"));
}
```

Comment: funciona de maravilla, ahora solo estoy topando en como mostrar la key "image" que es una url en un imageview ya que no es el mismo tratado que con un setText.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @SergioPeñafiel es correcta, la forma de obtener los datos de una colección , ahora como mostrarlos en pantalla?, puedes realizarlo dentro del mismo método `onPostExecute()` ya que ahí puedes realizar cambios en la UI, o puedes generar un objeto o listado de objetos para ser usados en algún otro punto en tu aplicación:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Collection<Map<String,String>> collection) {
    for(Map<String,String> item : collection){
           TextViewTitulo.setText(item.get("title"));
    }
}
```

Comment: si eso me resulta muy bien en los textview, solo que estoy topando en como arrojar la url "image" del json a un imageview, ya que el imageview.setImageResource pide un Int.

Comment: Si es una url de una imagen y la deseas poner en un ImageView , se debe descargar o se pueden usar otras opciones como Glide, Picasso. Si tienes problemas agrega una pregunta sobre eso y alguien te ayudara. Nativamente tiene que ser setImageBitmap()  ya que setImageResource() como su nombre lo indica trata de leer de los recursos y tiene que ser un int.

Answer (score 0):

obtuve la solucion gracias a ustedes chicos :)

comparto la solucion

```
protected void onPostExecute(Collection<Map<String,String>> collection) {
                    Log.d("HTTP",collection.toString());
        for(Map<String,String> elem : collection){
            Log.d("JSON",elem.get("title"));
            json.setText(elem.get("image"));
            //imagenjson.setImageBitmap(elem.get("image").toString());
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(elem.get("image")).into(imagenjson);

        }

    }
```

eternamente agradecido :) ya le di puntitos a sus respuestas :)